# Is it possible to reach same address in HD wallets?

Tags: private-key, bip32-hd-wallets

Is it possible to reach same address (same private key) with different mnemonics and different derivation paths in an implant based on BIP32,BIP39 & BIP44 combination?

Answer (score 2):

In theory it is possible to have a collision in this way. However in practice, doing so is basically the same as randomly generating new private keys and hoping for a collision.